# How to turn of css/javascript in parts of (divs?) html in combination with bootstrap

Tags: jquery, html, css

I like the fact that bootstrap has different features that can make a site beautiful and so.. but does anybody know a way in which i can turn of all the css (and maybe javascript too) in parts of my website, which of course contains some bootstrap elements but I want to use specific css in certain divs and be able to shut all currently loaded css up, except for e.g. one css file

My HTML are PHP generated and (sub) pages come in the same (overall) index environment.

Comment: Then why don't you just put your divs(that you want to add your own css) outside of any divs that are defined as any bootstrap div(container, row, col-md-*)?

Comment: because some bootstrap elements (eg. col-md) look nice, so i'd like to cancel out css IN a div and still be displaying stuff on the same absolute position: in that div.

Comment: like a table or a form, an li...

Comment: Why not simply cancel the attributes you don't want?

Comment: indeed, but how do i do this?